# MFC - Resize button accordingly to caption size

Tags: mfc

Hi i have a button (actually a  [Hyperlink](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3496/A-Better-Hyper-Link-Control?fid=14045&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&select=396314&fr=1)) and i want to resize the button to fit exactly the size of the text inserted with

```
this->m_jlcLink.SetDisplay(str);
```

how can i do that?

Comment: [CDC::DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6x7y2a4.aspx).

Comment: Read about `CWnd::SetWindowPos` and `CWnd::MoveWindow`. Then you will have the answer.

Comment: By the way, on that page the http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3496/A-Better-Hyper-Link-Control?msg=1853539#xx1853539xx comment can have some useful info for you.